# DNSMasq unknown interface wifi0 - failed to start

Tags: networking, 18.04, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi, dnsmasq

### Introduction

I am trying to use my Ubuntu Core-RaspberryPi as a Wifi Access point. Therefore, I am using **hostapd** and **dnsmasq**. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.cberner.com/2013/02/03/using-hostapd-on-ubuntu-to-create-a-wifi-access-point/) in order to setup everything.

**I start them manually - so all interfaces should be up and running when the services start.**

### HOSTAPD

**My hostapd.conf file:**

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=my_ap
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=my_password
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

**I added this line to /etc/default/hostapd:**

```
DAEMON_CONF=/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

### DNSMASQ

**I have the following dnsmasq.conf file:**

```
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=10.0.0.2,10.0.0.10,255.255.255.0,12h
no-hosts
addn-hosts=/etc/hosts.dnsmasq
```

**My etc/hosts.dnsmasq file:**

```
10.0.0.1 raspbi
```

**My etc/network/interfaces file:**

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 10.0.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

### EDIT: IP Address List Logs:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:46:24:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.68/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 86207sec preferred_lft 86207sec
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe46:2490/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:13:71:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

### What I get

> If I then try to start my dnsmasq by running `systemctl start dnsmasq` I
>   get an error ***"unknown interface wlan0"***.

### EDIT: What I tried

I also tried to force start **wlan0** by running `sudo ifconfig up wlan0` but still get the same error message

Comment: Please add the output of `ip address list` to your question, you also might want to remove sensitive data from that output before posting. Your interface name seems to be a different one than `wlan0`.

Comment: @Thomas please take a look at my edit.

Comment: Your `wlan0` interface is down. Try to bring it up with `ifup wlan0`.

Comment: @Thomas isn’t ifup outdated? I tried it today but I got the error message that the command could not be found...

Comment: You can use `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` to bring up the interface.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz I still get the same error, unfortunately this isn't working....

Comment: @Thomas I still get the same error message :/